# What is the std::mem_fn type equivalent to void(MainWindow::*handler)()?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a function:

```
std::function<void(sp_session*)> test(void(MainWindow::*handler)())
{
    return ...;
}
```

I would like to replace handler's type with the equivalent std::mem_fn type.

What is the type?

I tried this:

```
std::function<void(sp_session*)> test(std::mem_fn<void(), MainWindow>  handler)    
{
    return ...;
}
```

But VC++ 2010 spits out these errors:

```
error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'handler'
error C2059: syntax error : ')'
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?)
```

So I am not sure what I did wrong.

Comment: `mem_fn` is a function, not a type, you can't use it in this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::mem_fn` is not the type you are looking for.
The type you need is `std::function` that takes the instance as argument:

```
std::function<void(sp_session*)> test(std::function<void(MainWindow *)> handler)
```

It can bind to member function and is just used with the instance as first parameter.
If in the original function you would do:

```
instance->*handler();
```

In the new function you do:

```
handler(instance);
```

Comment: @Leith: `mem_fn` is a binder function that allows you to transform a member pointer to a function object, which can then be stored by `std::function`. It's the short-hand form of `std::bind(&T::member, _1, _2, _3, ...)` except that you don't need to know how many parameters you'll have. With `mem_fn`, it's just `std::mem_fn(&T::member)`.

Answer (score 4):

The exact type returned by the C++11 binder family of functions (`mem_fn`, `bind`) is *unspecified*, meaning it's an implementation detail and you shouldn't concern yourself with it.

`§20.8.9 [func.bind]`

> `template<class F, class... BoundArgs>`
>   *`unspecified`*`bind(F&&, BoundArgs&&...);`

`§20.8.10 [func.memfn]`

> `template<class R, class T>`
>     *`unspecified`*`mem_fn(R T::* pm);`

"Workaround": Use a template.

```
template<class F>
std::function<void(sp_session*)> test(F handler)
{
    return ...;
}
```